# overfloating row indicator in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I'm trying to append a row to an existing dataframe in R. The dataframe represents a subject and I want to update this with newly (generated) data. When I run this, the index numbers of the dataframe become strange:

1, 
2, 
21, 
211, 
2111, 
21111, etc.

These are not practicle to read. 
How to get 'normal' index numbers? (1, 2, 3, 4, etc.).

```
x <- 10
y <- 463
dat <- data.frame(x,y)

for (i in 1:10) {
dat.sub <- dat[nrow(dat),]       # select the last row from 'dat'
dat.sub <- within(dat.sub, {     # within that selection update the objects
    x <- x+1
    y <- y+1
})
dat <- rbind(dat, dat.sub, deparse.level = 2)   # attach updated row to the 'dat'
}

dat
dat[3,]
```

Comment: 1) Never grow an object in a loop (via `rbind`, `c`, `cbind`, etc.); pre-allocate the entire result before the loop and fill in the elements by subsetting. 2) you can set `rownames(dat) <- NULL` to set them to their "normal" numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `dat.sub` has `data.frame` class and has the same index number after second row. The easiest way is to change the class of `dat.sub` without assigning any index. One way is like:

```
dat.sub <- c(within(dat.sub, {     # within that selection update the objects
    x <- x+1
    y <- y+1
}))
```

add a `c` in your `for` loop, making `dat.sub` as a vector.

Comment: Thanks! However, I only want to update some of the variables in my more complex model (e.g. only update x) without having to assign _all_ objects in `c`. I added `rownames(dat.sub) <- NULL` after the `y <- y+1` as an alternative to the suggestion by @Jushua Ulrich. I don't see directly a problem with building a grow loop within an object. However, I'm not an experienced user.
Last note, I tried making a matrix subject, but unfortunately I can't use the `within` function on a matrix (or vector).